# how to read file into dictionary (seq_id and seq)?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary that has a seq_id and a list of sequences associated with that key. If anyone knows how to resolve this issue that would be much appreciated. Here is my code:

```
class Oragnise:
    def __init__(self, file):
        with open(file) as handle:
            self.sequences = {seq_id: seq for seq_id, seq in SimpleFastaParser(handle)}

def get_variant(self, variant=None):
    if variant is None:
        return list(self.sequences.values())
    return self.sequences.get(variant)

def get_num(self, variant=None):
    if variant is None:
        return {key: len(value) for key, value in self.sequences.items()}
    return len(self.sequences.get(variant))
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you just didn't make it a list (by using square brackets) in the `else` scenario?

Suggested code:

```py
def __init__(self, file):
    sequences = {}
    with open(file) as handle:
        for seq_id, seq in SimpleFastaParser(handle):
            if seq_id in sequences:
                sequences[seq_id].append(seq)
            else:
                sequences[seq_id] = [seq]  ## Change made here
    self.sequences = sequences
```

Comment: I believe you're correct, thank you!

Comment: Cool! If that works for you, and you believe this is a good answer, please accept it (to guide anyone else who searches the same thing in the future).

Answer (score 1):

You'll find *setdefault* useful here as follows:

```
def __init__(self, file):
    self.sequences = {}
    with open(file) as handle:
        for seq_id, seq in SimpleFastaParser(handle):
            self.sequences.setdefault(seq_id, []).append(seq)
```

...or...

```
self.sequences = {seq_id: seq for seq_id, seq in SimpleFastaParser(handle)}
```

Comment: use `defaultdict(list)`, your `or` will overwrite not append

Comment: @rioV8 The OP's code assigns a newly constructed dictionary to self.sequences. That's exactly what my code does. I do not see your point about defaultdict. It's not necessary

Comment: if you use `defaultdict` you don't need the `setdefault`

Comment: @rioV8 If I use setdefault I don't need a redundant import. How do you think defaultdict works under the covers? also, doing it this way means that self.sequences will be an instance of dict rather than defaultdict which is clearly what the OP intended

Comment: the alternative option `self.sequences = {seq_id: seq for seq_id, seq in SimpleFastaParser(handle)}` how do I save seq as a array list of seqs rather than one large string?

Comment: @user17976264 Neither of the options I've suggested will generate a string. In both cases you'll get a dictionary in the format as stated in your question. Did you try this code? Was there something about it that didn't match your requirement?

Comment: the first solution works as I want it too, key with a arraylist of values (seq). When I try to access them in the second solution it concatenates all seq into one entity, which is problematic when I try to determine number of sequences etc.

Comment: `with open(file) as handle:
            self.sequences = {seq_id: seq for seq_id, seq in SimpleFastaParser(handle)}`

Comment: When I try to get the len of a key's values it outputs the number of characters in the sequence rather than an a number of sequence instances which I got in the first suggestion

Comment: @user17976264 Edit your question to show what you've done

Comment: Done. With the second suggestion as implemented, when I call get num it will print 29,000+ rather than 1/5. I suspect it's counting the number of characters in the genome. An when I print the sequences dictionary it's just one large list of characters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242433/discussion-between-olvin-roght-and-user17976264).